# Will Recursively Calling Web Service in JavaScript Cause StackOverflow

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services, recursion, asp.net-web-api

I have a migration procedure that might take 2 to 3 days to finish. I'm afraid that the following implementation might raise a StackOverFlow exception due to the recursive aspect of it. Does JavaScript actually build a huge stack in order to execute this code? If so, what would be a better implementation? I might call this service about 10 millions times.

```
function mainFunc() {
        var url = getMyUrl();
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (remaining) {
                if(remaining > 0) {
                   mainFunc();
                }
                else {
                    alert('done');
                }
            },
            error: function (x, e) {
                alert('error!');
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this definitely doesn't sound like something that should be done from the browser, but handled server side instead.

That being said, Your recursion is happening asynchronously so a stack overflow won't happen for sure.
Depending on your exact code ( more specifically, which values exactly are being included in the closures ), this might start piling up memory. You will also be using additionally memory because the success and error function's will be re-created every-time you call `mainFunc`.

You can solve this function memory allocation issue fairly easiliy by declaring those functions outside `mainFunc` and then pass a reference to them inside the `mainFunc` function.

Doing this won't absolve you completely from preventing a memory exception off course. This really depends on the actually code and what references you are keeping on each iteration.

In order to determine if your code is hanging on to resources during this long process, you will ether have to read the code and figure out where you're code is "leaking", or dive into memory profiling options:

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling

Example to factor out closures:

```
function mainFuncSuccess(remaining) {
    if(remaining > 0) {
       mainFunc();
    }
    else {
        alert('done');
    }
}


function mainFuncError() {
    alert('error!');
}

function mainFunc() {
        var url = getMyUrl();
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: mainFuncSuccess,
            error: mainFuncError
        });
    }
```

Comment: declaring the functions outside like this? `success: callSuccess(remaining);` where `callSuccess` calls `mainFunc()`?

Comment: Do you know if I can put `remaining` as a parameter in `mainFuncSuccess`? `remaining` is undefined now.

Answer (score 1):

Because `$.ajax` is asynchronous, it won't invoke the `success` function until after the remote server responds. In other words, after each iteration, the JS engine will essentially 'sleep' until it gets response, then resume with the `success` function. So this technically isn't an example of recursion. The stack should stay fairly small, no matter how many iterations it takes (assuming there aren't other factors you haven't shown here that contribute to the stack).

Answer (score 1):

No, because you're not storing anything inside of mainFunc that needs to be used later. There are not any objects that need to be stored in the scope of the function.

In chrome you can check memory with window.performance.memory

Comment: You don't need to store anything outside of the function in order to get a stack overflow (try `(function foo(){ foo(); })()`).

Comment: It's a simplified example, it will really depend on exactly what his code is going to look like.